# Reverse join in node js with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, aggregate

I have two documents

> Users (_id, name)
>   Dealer (user_id, address)

I Want to access dealer detail from users using aggregate. Is it possible? 
I have tried following

```js
User.aggregate([
       {
         $lookup: {
           from: "dealer",
           localField: "_id",
           foreignField: "user_id",
           as: "dealer_detail"
         }
       },
      {
        $project: {
          name: "$name",
          dealer_detail: "$dealer_detail"
        }
      }
    ]);
```

But it is returning empty array for dealer_detail.

Comment: `foreignField: "userid",` => maybe this should be  `foreignField: "user_id",` as you said `Dealer (user_id, address)`. Also be sure to use the collection name (physical) in from field. So is your dealer collection name really `dealer_info`?

Comment: can you add sample documents in json format for users and dealers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct for accessing dealer details.
There might some possibility that can help you out.

1) Make sure your "**from**" field is same as you define in you model, there might case sensitive error.

2) In your dealer model "**user_id**" is type of "**ObjectId**". If it is in type **String** the aggregation wan't able to fetch the dealer details.